# HTTP Server issues

Tags: java, http, server, bufferedoutputstream

Hi guys i have a very basic http server coded in about 30 minutes for an assignment and have come across a very weird problem. We were specified to use only BufferedOutputStream instead of a StreamWriter as there is apparently an issue with using PrintWriters as they perform differently on different platforms. I am confused as i have the follwoing println method...

```
private void println(BufferedOutputStream bos, String s) throws IOException {
    String toPrint = s + "\r\n";
    byte[] array = toPrint.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        bos.write(array[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

I am confused as when using

```
println(outStream,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
println(outStream,"");
println(outStream,"Hello World");
```

the webpage says i have not sent any data but using...

```
writer.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
writer.println("");
writer.println("Hello World");
```

everything appears perfectly.. ive tried a few things such as flushing the outStstream but i dont understand why it wont work

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you flushed and closed your BufferedOutputStream after writing all the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void println(BufferedOutputStream bos, String s) throws IOException {
    String toPrint = s + "\r\n";
    byte[] array = toPrint.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        bos.write(array[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

You don't need all that. In fact you don't need any of it. Just call `bos.write((s+"\r\n").getBytes())` directly from wherever you're calling it, and then flush it when you've written everything you need to write.

Note that in HTTP 1.1 you either have to close the `BufferedOutputStream` or provide a `Content-length` header (or use chunked transfer encoding).